# write a query to calculate age till date and find nth highest age from employee table

Tags: sql, oracle

```
ID       || birthdate
------------------------ 
1        || 25-10-1994
2        || 1-6-1990
3        || 4-12-2006
```

how to calculate age and how to get nth highest age.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `months_between` with `row_number` like this

```
select m.age from 
    (select s.age, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.age ORDER BY s.age desc) rownumber  
       from (select MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, birthdate )/12 age from myTable) s) m
where m.rownumber = 1 -- or your nth highest age row, for example 11 ))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unaware of Oracle syntax for SQL query but you can create the query as follows:

1. Sort the date column by ascending order.
2. Set results limit to 1 & offset to `N` i.e. Nth largest.
3. Use select to print that date column subtracted from current date to get present age.

Comment: limit does not use in oracle

Comment: @PrashantTendulkar  you can use [row limiting clause](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1) in oracle.

Answer (score 0):

The age can simply be calculated by subtracting the birtdate from `sysdate`. That will return the age in days. Once you have that, this is a typical [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) query. You can use e.g. a window function to filter out the n oldest:

```
select id, birthdate, "Age in days"
from (
  select id,
         birthdate, 
         sysdate - birthdate as "Age in days",
         row_number() over (order by sysdate - birthdate desc) as rn
  from emps
) 
where rn <= 2 -- or whatever limit you want
order by 3;
```